# How to get images of a record from database with laravel?

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables one store stuff information and one store stuff images

**-table stuffs**

```
stuff_id |  name  | detail
```

**-table images**

```
id  | stuff_id  | images
```

**-my model relationship**

```
-Stuffs

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Stuffs extends Model
{
// A Stuff has many images
 public function image(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Model\image', 'stuff_id');
}
}


-Image

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
{
// images belongs to only one Stuff
public function stuff(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Stuffs');
{
{
```

Now I get some stuff info and look like this:

```
ID  | Name
1   |[July][1]
2   |[Bona][1]
```

I need that if I click on that stuff's name it will go to detail page with all the images of the stuff has.

**My Detail Page**

```
@foreach($getDetails as $getDetail)
<a rel="lightbox" data-lightbox = "gallery" href="{{URL::asset($getDetail->images)}}">
 <img class="img-responsive" width="150" src="{{URL::asset($getDetail->images)}}">
 </a>
 @endforeach
```

**My Controller**

```
public function Detail($id){
$getDetails = Image::join('Stuffs', 'stuffs.stuff_id' , '=', 'image.stuff_id')
 ->find($id);
 return view('crud.more_detail', compact('getDetails'));
}
}
```

**It is not work and get this error**

```
ErrorException in b5e95ef79c2c035f3a379c139e5e7ac6 line 11:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: 
C:\wamp\www\crud\resources\views\crud\more_detail.blade.php)
```

Please help me thanks;

Comment: what is the line number `11` in `more_detail.blade.php`?

Comment: It just the detail name page

Comment: the code @foreach($getDetails as $getDetail)
<a rel="lightbox" data-lightbox = "gallery" href="{{URL::asset($getDetail->images)}}">
 <img class="img-responsive" width="150" src="{{URL::asset($getDetail->images)}}">
 </a>
 @endforeach   is in that page

Answer (score 0):

One of the main points of using relationships is that you don't have to manually join tables together.

To get an image with it's stuff you would just need to do:

```
$getDetails = Image::with('stuff')->find($id); 
//'stuff' is the name of the method you're using in your model
```

Also, using`find()` will only return the row where the id of that row is equal to `$id` so looping through `$getDetails` won't work. This is most likely the reason you're getting an error.

If you want to get all images and their stuff you could do:

```
$getDetails = Image::with('stuff')->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which bit didn't work? Was there an error message? etc